# Send data to iframe from parent page or retrieve data from the iframe

Tags: javascript, json, iframe

I have an iframe in the page with source to another page inside the iframe (index.html):

In parent page I have some json which I need to send to iframe (or in other words iframe on document ready needs to retrieve this json)

(iframe lies on the same domain as parent page)

My question is, is it better to send this json data to iframe or retrieve it from the iframe itself?

What is general code better and easier?

Comment: It depends. If the data (and code it produces) is used by the only document in iframe then it is better to put it to the doc in iframe. If you change src's of iframe and all these docs use same code (and/or data) then the code should be in outer document.

Comment: Forgot to mention, parent page receives json from the server, then its just the question weather is better to send this json to iframe or retrieve it from the iframe?

Comment: The answer is the same. If you don't change doc in iframe and data is used by iframe only then place code into iframe doc. else in parent doc.

Comment: Ok. And how do I send json to that iframe when iframe has finished loading?